# Can I use an Outlook Add-In from macro code?

Tags: vba, outlook, com, outlook-addin

Is it possible to execute an Outlook Add-In or access it's properties from within Outlook's own VBA code?  Or are Add-Ins completely isolated from macro development?

I am trying to extend the use of the Skype for Business Add-In (UCAddin.dll).

Answer (score 0):

No they are no isolated.

Just add a new COM Object (maybe a singleton) that is supported by your addin, with the interface you need. Use CreateObject inside the macro code and you have access to your special interface and the internals of your addin...

Answer (score 0):

If it is your own addin, then yes - your code can access the `Application.COMAddins` collection, find the addin, and use `COMAddin.Object` property. Your addin in turn has to expose an object in that COMAddin.Object property - to do that, it needs to set the property on the COMAddin object passed as a parameter when processing the `IDTExtensbility2.OnConnection` callback.

That being said, I don't think Skype addin exposes anything through the `COMAddin.Object` property.

Answer (score 0):

See [Walkthrough: Calling Code in a VSTO Add-in from VBA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608614.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

You must know public APIs available in add-ins. Or follow the contract/interface which is available publicly.